# Android xml layout for multiple buttons on one page

Tags: android

I wanted to add one circular button on the center of screen and four circular buttons around it in android layout. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relative layout and adjust gravity for all 5 buttons to top|left,  top|end,  bottom|left,  bottom|end.  For the 5th button set gravity to centre

Comment: Thanks Anshul for the help.